# Multiple sites and url management

Tags: link-manager

I'm having some problems configuring sitecore the way I need. I have 3 sites:

- Content

  - Site1
  - Site2
  - Site3

Site1 url should be `www.site1.com`

Site2 url should be `www.site2.com`

Site3 url should be `www.site2.com/subsection/site3`

Now obviously my problem is with Site3, I managed to configure it in the desired url but I'm having issues with the language specific urls. I need them to be like this:

- `www.site2.com/subsection/site3/en`
- `www.site2.com/subsection/site3/es`

But it seems instead I have

- `www.site2.com/en/subsection/site3`
- `www.site2.com/es/subsection/site3`

This doesn't work for me because I need to have site3 all under the root of `www.site2.com/subsection/site3`

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Sitecore always embeds the language as the first part of the URL. I would suggest that you leave it as it and not try to move it to the end of the site3 URL. You'll need a bunch of customizations to make it work and a lot of testing for edge cases. Furthermore, I have no idea if you'll have knock on effect for SEO/crawlers due to changing location of the language, I would leave it as `www.site2.com/en/subsection/site3`

Comment: If you need you can achieve this by using virtualFolder/physicalFolder properties on site definitions. But, in that scenario, you will have to add lot of site definitions for each site and for each language of those sites (since when using the above way, you will have to disable language embedding and language code should be added as virtualFolder/physicalFolder path). But, I think as @jammykam mention, you should try to use language as first part of the url due to the same reason he has mention and for ease of your solution configuration.

Comment: I need to keep track of site2 and site3 separately in google analytics, how can I do that if I have 2 different roots (1 for each language).

Comment: I agree with @jammykam, not to handle by customizing anything. This is quite possible to achieve using Reverse Proxy or any Load Balancer (if supports reverse proxy mechanism). I do not recommend using it, but it's the way of achieving this. Using it depends on the reason business needs. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/

If you use separate layouts or separate GA settings (accounts/Site in GA) for both sites, it's possible to have analytics separately.

Comment: At the end I remembered I could change the language with a parameter (sc_lang) instead so I guess that kinda solves the issue. Thanks.